# Update app permissions in my dropbox developer app

Tags: python, dropbox

I have created an app in dropbox, however whenever I update the permissions for my app, and refresh the page, I lose all my updated permissions. Where do I save them?
[image]

Once I refresh the tab:

[image]

This is not just a visual glitch, as when I run the code

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
def dropbox_list_files(path):
    """Return a Pandas dataframe of files in a given Dropbox folder path in the Apps directory.
    """


    try:
        files = dbx.files_list_folder(path).entries
        files_list = []
        for file in files:
            if isinstance(file, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                metadata = {
                    'name': file.name,
                    'path_display': file.path_display,
                    'client_modified': file.client_modified,
                    'server_modified': file.server_modified
                }
                files_list.append(metadata)

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(files_list)
        return df.sort_values(by='server_modified', ascending=False)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error getting list of files from Dropbox: ' + str(e))

print(dropbox_list_files("/"))
```

I get the error:
`Error getting list of files from Dropbox: BadInputError('**String of data**', 'Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": Your app is not permitted to access this endpoint because it does not have the required scope \'files.metadata.read\'. The owner of the app can enable the scope for the app using the Permissions tab on the App Console.')`
How can I save my new permissions so that I don't get this error anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Submit" button in the bar floating at the bottom of the page you need to use to save the changes you apply.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It was hidden under the "Accept cookies" bar which I have trained myself to ignore